# How to get focus from child dialog and parent dialog

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I Have one parent dialog and one child dialog, when I loaded child dialog in parent dialog the  focus is not coming on parent dialog`s control, what I do to get focus on parent dialog control?

Comment: Have you looked at SetFocus ()?

Comment: yes i have used setfoucus, what i am doing have one dialog (parent), i have other 6 dialogs, i am loading these dialogs into parent dialog, the foucs is coming on last loaded dialog,when i operate by tab key the focus is moving in only child dialog, when last control of cheld dialog gets focus the focus should be on parent dialog control ,but it is not happening

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, I would assume that this is a problem with [dialog styles](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/29fad834-c536-4d74-8d1f-00bf04d033f2/tab-order-in-dialog).  In particular, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT.

Comment: Thank u sir, i used the  WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT propterty and i also set the control parent to true of both child and parent dialogs property, now its working